# Replacing single digit numbers with sed

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have the following problem to solve:

Using the sed shell command replace all the single digit numbers with their "spoken out" counterpart. Multiple digit numbers should remain unchanged. It should work even if the number is on the beginning or the end of the line.

For example: 5 word 23 word 1 word -> five word 23 word one word

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried and how is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

To isolate a single digit from multiples, you can use \b (boundary) like this:

```
echo "5 word 23 word 1 word" | sed 's/\b1\b/one/g;s/\b2\b/two/g'
```

Replacing the unmentioned digits is left as an exercise for the user.